# Regexp: Replace only in specific context

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In a text, I would like to replace all occurrences of `$word` by `[$word]($word)` (to create a link in Markdown), but only if it is not already in a link. Example:

`[$word homepage](http://w00tw00t.org)`

should **not** become

`[[$word]($word) homepage](http://w00tw00t.org)`.

Thus, I need to check whether $word is somewhere between [ and ] and only replace if it's not the case.

Can you think of a preg_replace command for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't as simple as you might think. The previous answers would fail in many situations. Here's one that should replace every $word that's not inside [] already:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\G((?:[^\[]|\[[^\]]*\])*?)('.$word.')/', '$1[$2]($2)', $text)
```

If $word contains special regexp characters, you might want to `preg_quote` it.

**Example**

```
$text = 'aa foo bb [foo bar](http://example.com) cc foo dd';
$word = 'foo';
$text = preg_replace('/\G((?:[^\[]|\[[^\]]*\])*?)('.$word.')/', '$1[$2]($2)', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

`aa [foo](foo) bb [foo bar](http://example.com) cc [foo](foo) dd`

Comment: Even if `$word` does not contain special regexp characters, you might want to `preg_quote()` it. Simply because it is The Right Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

i think

<s>"~$word(?!.*?])~"</s>

```
 "~$word(?=[^\[\]]*(\[|$))~"
```

e.g.

```
$src = "aa foo [ bbb foo xyz ] cc foo dd";
$word = "foo";
print preg_replace("~$word(?=[^\[\]]*(\[|$))~", "[FOO](bar)", $src);
```